# Access variable with a key value defined in one function in other functions within a package

Tags: variables, go, scope, global-variables

I have a file name one.go as follows,

one.go:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    keys, ok := r.URL.Query()["key"]

    if !ok || len(keys) < 1 {
        log.Println("Url Param 'key' is missing")
        return
    }
    key := keys[0]

    log.Println("Url Param 'key' is: " + string(key))
}
```

I need to access this variale "key" in my main.go program.
Please help.

Tried declaring another variable var Test = key in one.go and then while trying to access it in main.go getting the error "undefined Test"

Comment: are you trying to access a variable declared in a function? That's impossible, its scope is local. You need to use global variables instead. And yes, they need to be exported (start with uppercase). I recommend you take the [go tour](https://tour.golang.org/)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I really doubt you want to access a variable that is specific to an HTTP request in your `main.go` directly. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It seem very likely you are going to need a `session`. A global variable would mess up if it is a "user-specified" value.

Answer (score -1):

For accessing value you needs to import your one.go variable in your main.go. Declare a struct in your one.go and assign your key to struct variable and then call the struct in main.go. For eg :-

```
package one

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Value struct{
  key string
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    keys, ok := r.URL.Query()["key"]

    if !ok || len(keys) < 1 {
        log.Println("Url Param 'key' is missing")
        return
    }
}

func GetValue() *Value {
    key := &Value{
        "keyvalue",
    }
    return key
}
```

You can access that variable using one.Value by returning from the function or assign the value to a struct and then call the struct in your main file

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/project/new/one"
)

func main() {
    // log.Println(one.Key)
    store := one.GetValue()
    log.Println(store)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem related to the question, which is about accessing a *variable* globally, not about exporting a *type*.

Comment: Main question was to use a variable in another file that can be possible either by creating a global variable or initialising it and exporting. Don't just down vote without knowing the actual meaning of question

Comment: I do know the meaning of the question, but you don't seem to. "Go is a static type language." is completely irrelevant to a question of creating a global variable. The question has nothing whatsoever to do with types, only with scope. The question states "I need to access this variale "key" in my main.go program." This does not require defining a new `Value` type as you've done in the answer - that's totally pointless and unnecessary.  The asker just wants a simple `string`.

Comment: Sorry buddy the user just wants to export the value and use it in main.go file `I need to access this variale "key" in my main.go program`. User does not ask for a global variable.All user asked for using the value in main.go. I know how to use global variable.

Comment: Fair enough, they want global access, not *necessarily* a global variable. That still doesn't explain why your answer involves defining a new, pointless type, nor why it only allows returning a static, constant value, which doesn't help with the question at all.

Comment: So finally you agreed about my logic here. We are here to help people with solutions or options if the question is not exact.